# how to implement the aodv protocol in ns2

Tags: c++, protocols, ns2

this is some part of my file AODV.tcl example of AODV implementation in ns2 the problem that i need to use the aodv.c and aodv.h in this implementation i don't know how to do this ?? i need to use all the functions in aodv.c file and i don't know how to do it? please help and thanks .

```
my code:
set ns [new Simulator]
set namfile [open AODV_final.nam w]
set Time [open time.tr w]
...
global TN
set TN 2
set god_ [create-god $TN]
$ns node-config -adhocRouting AODV \
         -llType LL \
     -macType Mac/802_11\
     -ifqLen 50 \
     -ifqType Queue/DropTail/PriQueue \
     -antType Antenna/OmniAntenna \
     -propType Propagation/TwoRayGround \
     -phyType Phy/WirelessPhy \
     -channel [new Channel/WirelessChannel] \
     -topoInstance $topography \
     -agentTrace ON \
     -routerTrace ON \
     -macTrace ON \
             -movementTrace ON

     set x1 150
     set y1 150
     ...
for {set j1 0} {$j1 < $TN} {incr j1 20} {
incr x1 0
incr y1 150
$node($j1) set X_ $x1
$node($j1) set Y_ $y1
$node($j1) set Z_ 0
$node($j1) color "green"
$ns at 0.000000 "$node($j1) setdest $x1 $y1 0.00"

}
...
$ns at 10.000000 "$node(0) setdest 160 450 75"
$ns connect $Tcp(0) $TcpSink(1)
$ns at 0.020000 "$Ftp(0) start"
$ns at 590.000000 "$Ftp(0) stop"
...
proc finish {} {
global ns namfile  
$ns flush-trace
close $namfile
exit 0
}
$ns at 10.000000 "finish"
$ns run
```

Comment: You should update your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760522/how-to-edit-my-tcl-file-of-protocol-aodv) instead of reposting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

"aodv.c" : The ns2 file name is aodv.cc .

`ns2´ works this way : All functions in the C++ and tcl/lib/** files are compiled into the executable 'ns'. At simulation time these files are used : /usr/local/bin/ns , ns-allinone-2.3x/{ bin/tcsh8, lib/*/* }.

All other file can actually be deleted : And you can have your simulation example(s) in any random location.

---

AODV examples : aodv_ex_04.2015.tar.gz

→ https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNZFlsVXhpcHZ2NFE/view?usp=sharing

---

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)